# How to differentiate first and last position of wrapped text in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a `contentEditable span` where I want to place a `position: absolute` element on the same line as the cursor. The problem happens when the text gets wrapped because it doesn't fit - the first and last position of the wrapped lines have weird behaviours.

For both of them, when I am at the first position in the second line the `y` offset of `getBoundingClientRect()` is equal to offset of the first line, however if I move one place further on second line the `y offset` is correctly matching the second line.

In the snippet below this behaviour is displayed for Firefox. For Chrome it seems to work fine although in my full implementation it also has imprecise behavior, but I was able to solve it for chrome. However for Firefox the last position of first line has `offset` equal to the first line, the first position on second line has `offset` equal to the first line, afterwards it works fine.

In the example, go to the last place on first line and notice the `CURRENT_TOP` value in the console says `16`. If you go one place right so the cursor is already on next line, it still says `16`. if you move one more right, it will say `36`

```js
const textEl = document.getElementById("myText")

textEl.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  const domSelection = window.getSelection();
  if (domSelection && domSelection.isCollapsed && domSelection.anchorNode) {
    let offsetNewLine = 0;

    const domRange = domSelection.getRangeAt(0);
    const rect = domRange.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rects = domRange.getClientRects();
    const newRange = document.createRange();
    const newRangeNextOffset = domSelection.anchorNode.textContent.length < domSelection.anchorOffset + 1 ? domSelection.anchorOffset : domSelection.anchorOffset + 1

    newRange.setStart(domSelection.anchorNode, newRangeNextOffset);
    newRange.setEnd(domSelection.anchorNode, newRangeNextOffset);
    const nextCharacterRect = newRange.getBoundingClientRect();

    console.log(`CURRENT_TOP: ${rect.y}, NEXT_CHAR_TOP: ${nextCharacterRect.y}`);
  }
})
```

```css
.text-container {
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="myText" class="text-container" contentEditable="true">Go on the last position in the first row and come it to first position in the second row</span>
```

Comment: Note that the `console.log()` line in your fiddle was using broken syntax. I corrected this for you and moved the code in to an inline snippet, where you're more likely to get some answers because it's much easier for people to see the code you're talking about

Comment: I'm using Firefox and I get a value of `15.5` for text on the first line and `35.5` for text on the second line. From what I can tell, it seems to work for me unless I'm missing something

Comment: @ChrisBarr the problem is specifically if you are at the very beginning of second line, it shows you CURRENT_TOP the same value as first line. Is this working for you if you are at these positions ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not read the specific instructions. No in that position is it reporting as you have described.

Comment: Not able to come up with a completely working solution, however: When I logged what `domSelection.anchorNode.textContent[newRangeNextOffset]` was to show me what it thought the next letter was, it was one ahead of where I expect it to be. I was able to fix this by moving the `+1` in the ternary statement that sets what the value of `newRangeNextOffset` is. Why not just use `domRange.endOffset` to get the cursor position?

Comment: `DomSelection` and `domRange` are collapsed, but  `domSelection.anchorNode.textContent[domRange.endOffset]` will display the character that is on the right from cursor. When you are at the end of the first line then the next character is `" "`, so my idea was to get the next next character position and check if that one is already on the second line, but it's not enough, because first position on second line is still equal to first line. I could do currentOffset + 2, but that would not work with chrome because it would assume I am on second line one character too early.

Comment: We see that Chrome and Firefox behave differently when new line. But what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @rtom : Unluckily you can't do simply `currentOffset + 2` on Firefox either, as FF doesn't increment the offset on the newline as one would expect. See my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77493525/19980636) below for details.

Comment: @rtom -- I got a workaround. Firefox behaves now like Chrome. See my answer below. I'm adding some comments in the moment.

Comment: Note: *Almost* like Chrome. Firefox' space on the end of line 1 remains, of course, but I assume that you don't care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the diagnosis, then the treatment.

### Diagnosis

This strange behavior occurs thanks to the fact, that Chrome and Firefox seemingly treat the wrap-newline differently. Execute the following snippet in Chrome and Firefox. The only difference is, that I added

```
anchorOffset: ${domSelection.anchorOffset}
```

to the console output. We'll discuss the results below.

```js
const textEl = document.getElementById("myText")

textEl.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  const domSelection = window.getSelection();
  if (domSelection && domSelection.isCollapsed && domSelection.anchorNode) {
    let offsetNewLine = 0;

    let domRange = domSelection.getRangeAt(0);
    let rect = domRange.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rects = domRange.getClientRects();
    const newRange = document.createRange();
    const newRangeNextOffset = domSelection.anchorNode.textContent.length < domSelection.anchorOffset + 1 ? domSelection.anchorOffset : domSelection.anchorOffset + 1

    newRange.setStart(domSelection.anchorNode, newRangeNextOffset);
    newRange.setEnd(domSelection.anchorNode, newRangeNextOffset);
    let nextCharacterRect = newRange.getBoundingClientRect();

    console.log(`anchorOffset: ${domSelection.anchorOffset}, CURRENT_TOP: ${rect.y}, NEXT_CHAR_TOP: ${nextCharacterRect.y}`);
  }
})
```

```css
.text-container {
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="myText" class="text-container" contentEditable="true">Go on the last position in the first row and come it to first position in the second row</span>
```

The browsers wrap at different positions here, but that's not the point. Look at the output in **Chrome** first. Note, that the [caret](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Caret) jumps directly to the next line, the actually existing space has been *transformed* to a newline (NL), and seemingly in the classical Carriage Return plus Line Feed (CR+LF) form. So after the NL Chrome sees the cursor, like the human eye, already on Line 2.

| last non-whitespace at line 1 | wrapping-newline | first non-whitespace at line 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 't' at offset 61 | NL at offset 62 | 'p' at offset 63 |

[image: chrome]

Now **Firefox**. The caret follows the space and *then* jumps to the next line. The space (SP) has been preserved. However the *inserted* newline has *not* been included into the offset-calculation. Further, it is still treated as part of line 1, i.e. the human eye sees the cursor on line 2, but Firefox on line 1. Whyever.

So Firefox iterates *twice* at the end of line 1 (SP then NL), but increments the offset only *once* (for SP and NL together), and without having really moved to line 2 yet. All that makes things so messy here.

| last non-whitespace at line 1 | wrapping-newline | first non-whitespace at line 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'n' at offset 73 | SP *and* NL, both at offset 74 | 't' at offset 75 |

[image: firefox]

### Treatment

The only way I currently can think of is to [detect the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browsers#9851769) and introduce a Firefox-specific workaround, so to check on Firefox e.g. with

```
const isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
```

Tested, and still works, with Firefox 111.

So, we could bridge the problem by denoting whether we are in a Firefox-newline. Let us add some globals first:

```
// whether we're in a (Firefox-)NL
let isNewline = false;
// whether we're in Firefox
const isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
```

Note, that one can use `isNewline` also for other browsers if necessary. Next we add the Firefox-specific line-hopping into the `keyup` handler:

```
/*
* Check whether we're in Firefox and on the edge of a line.
* At need easily extendable for other browsers.
*/
if(isFirefox && rect.y < nextCharacterRect.y)
{
    // caret is after the SP, i.e. we're in the NL-sequence
    if(isNewline)
    {
        /*
        * Hop straight to the next line by
        * de facto enforcing a LF+CR.
        */
        domRange = newRange;
        domSelection.getRangeAt(0);
        rect = domRange.getBoundingClientRect();

        // end of Firefox' NL-sequence
        isNewline = false;
    }
    // begin of Firefox' NL-sequence, i.e. we hit the SP
    else
        isNewline = true;
}
```

This may be extended e.g. by selection direction detection for fine-tuning.

Lets put everything together in the following snippet. Note, that `domRange` resp. `rect` became `let` instead of `const`.

```js
// our denotation values, see above
let isNewline = false;
const isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

const textEl = document.getElementById("myText")

textEl.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  const domSelection = window.getSelection();
  if (domSelection && domSelection.isCollapsed && domSelection.anchorNode) {
    let offsetNewLine = 0;

    let domRange = domSelection.getRangeAt(0);
    let rect = domRange.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rects = domRange.getClientRects();
    const newRange = document.createRange();
    const newRangeNextOffset = domSelection.anchorNode.textContent.length < domSelection.anchorOffset + 1 ? domSelection.anchorOffset : domSelection.anchorOffset + 1

    newRange.setStart(domSelection.anchorNode, newRangeNextOffset);
    newRange.setEnd(domSelection.anchorNode, newRangeNextOffset);
    const nextCharacterRect = newRange.getBoundingClientRect();

    // the line-hopping, see above
    if(isFirefox && rect.y < nextCharacterRect.y)
    {
        if(isNewline)
        {
            domRange = newRange;
            domSelection.getRangeAt(0);
            rect = domRange.getBoundingClientRect();
            isNewline = false;
        }
        else
            isNewline = true;
    }

    console.log(`anchorOffset: ${domSelection.anchorOffset}, CURRENT_TOP: ${rect.y}, NEXT_CHAR_TOP: ${nextCharacterRect.y}`);
  }
})
```

```css
.text-container {
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="myText" class="text-container" contentEditable="true">Go on the last position in the first row and come it to first position in the second row</span>
```

### Conclusion

There may be a more elegant and sophisticated solution, but for now it does the job. Essentially we're modding Firefox' line-wrapping behavior by enforcing a `LF+CR` type of newline à la Chrome. The only remaining difference is the additional space at the end of line before the actual wrapping, i.e. in Firefox we still have to press the key twice to get to the next line, instead of once as in Chrome. But that's pretty irrelevant here. Otherwise the behavior of both browsers is now equivalent. Furthermore, this workaround can easily be adapted for other browsers, if necessary.

---

###### Acknowledgement

The final spark of inspiration for using a newline-denotation variable came through a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77508534/19980636) by [@herrstrietzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15015675/herrstrietzel), where also approaches to consider the selection direction and mouse interaction are discussed.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by [@Krokomot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474614/how-to-differentiate-first-and-last-position-of-wrapped-text-in-firefox#77493525) Firefox has a quirky way to treat line wraps.

In fact both the end of the previous line *and* the start of the current line (showing the cursor/caret) will return the same character index/position (or `anchorOffset` value).

A workaround might be to save the last character index as well as the last top `y` value in  global variables.

If the current character position and the previous top y  equal the previous ones

– we take the y position calculated from the next character (`anchorOffset + 1`) – in this case after the line break.

```js
const textEl = document.getElementById("myText");
let bbText = textEl.getBoundingClientRect();
let textElTop = bbText.top;
let textElRight = bbText.right;

let lastCharPos = 0;
let lastTop = 0;

myText.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  updateSelection(e);
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  updateSelection(e);
});

function updateSelection(e) {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  let caret = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  let range = document.createRange();
  let {
    anchorNode,
    anchorOffset
  } = selection;
  range.setStart(anchorNode, anchorOffset);

  // get y pos of next character
  let anchorOffset2 =
    anchorOffset < anchorNode.textContent.length - 1 ?
    anchorOffset + 1 :
    anchorOffset;

  let rangeN = document.createRange();
  rangeN.setStart(anchorNode, anchorOffset2);

  let bb = caret.getBoundingClientRect();
  let bb2 = rangeN.getBoundingClientRect();

  let height = bb.height;
  let top = bb.top - textElTop;
  let top2 = bb2.top - textElTop;



  // check mouse position on click
  let mouseX = e.pageX ? e.pageX : 0;
  let distX = mouseX ? Math.abs(bb.left - mouseX) : 0;
  let distX2 = mouseX ? Math.abs(bb2.left - mouseX) : 0;



  if (
    ((lastTop && lastTop == top && lastCharPos == anchorOffset) ||
      (lastTop && lastTop != top && lastCharPos < anchorOffset)
    ) ||
    (distX > distX2)
  ) {
    top = top2;
  }

  if (distX < distX2) {
    top = bb.top - textElTop;
  }

  // update
  lastCharPos = anchorOffset;
  lastTop = top;
  mouseX = 0;

  // shift line indicator
  selectionLine.setAttribute("style", `top:${top}px; height:${height}px;`);
  cursor.setAttribute("style", `top:${bb.top}px; left:${bb.left}px;`);


}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 11px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.text-container {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.text-container:focus+.selectionLine {
  border-left: 10px solid green;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1em;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.2em;
  height: 0.2em;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="info" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0;"></div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="myText" class="text-container" contentEditable="true">Go on the last position in the first row and come it to first position in the second row.
  </div>
  <div id="selectionLine" class="selectionLine"></div>
</div>

<div id="cursor"></div>
```

The above examples also check new caret positions based on mouse inputs.

However, this approach still fails when using up/down arrow keys.

Red spot indicates the native caret position – which can't be fixed. Green bar represents the fixed y offset.

#### Include selection direction (forward or backwards)

We're also checking for key inputs like `"ArrowLeft"`, `"ArrowUp"` to adjust caret position.

Pretty clunky, but this way we get a decent support for arrow-key navigation.

This example also includes a Firefox user detection as suggested by @Krokomot.

```js
const textEl = document.getElementById("myText");
let bbText = textEl.getBoundingClientRect();
let textElTop = bbText.top;
let textElRight = bbText.right;

let lastCharPos = 0;
let lastTop = 0;
let forwards = true;

// simple firefox agent detection
const isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== "undefined";

myText.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  updateSelection(e);
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  updateSelection(e);
});

function updateSelection(e) {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  let caret = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  let range = document.createRange();
  let { anchorNode, anchorOffset } = selection;
  range.setStart(anchorNode, anchorOffset);

  let bb = caret.getBoundingClientRect();
  let height = bb.height;
  let top = bb.top - textElTop;

  if (isFirefox) {
    // get y pos of next character
    let anchorOffset2 =
      anchorOffset < anchorNode.textContent.length - 1
        ? anchorOffset + 1
        : anchorOffset;

    let anchorOffset3 = anchorOffset > 0 ? anchorOffset - 1 : anchorOffset;

    let rangeN = document.createRange();
    rangeN.setStart(anchorNode, anchorOffset2);

    let rangeP = document.createRange();
    rangeP.setStart(anchorNode, anchorOffset3);

    let bb2 = rangeN.getBoundingClientRect();
    let bb0 = rangeP.getBoundingClientRect();

    let top2 = bb2.top - textElTop;
    let top0 = bb0.top - textElTop;

    // check mouse position on click
    let mouseX = e.pageX ? e.pageX : 0;
    let mouseY = e.pageY ? e.pageY : 0;

    // check keybord inputs
    let key = e.key ? e.key : "";

    let distX = mouseX ? Math.abs(bb.left - mouseX) : 0;
    let distX2 = mouseX ? Math.abs(bb2.left - mouseX) : 0;

    let distY = mouseY ? Math.abs(bb.top - mouseY) : 0;
    let distY2 = mouseY ? Math.abs(bb2.top - mouseY) : 0;

    // direction: forward or backward
    if (
      lastCharPos > anchorOffset ||
      key === "ArrowLeft" ||
      key === "ArrowUp" ||
      (distY && distY < distY2)
    ) {
      forwards = false;
    } else if (
      lastCharPos < anchorOffset ||
      key === "ArrowRight" ||
      key === "ArrowDown" ||
      (distY && distY > distY2)
    ) {
      forwards = true;
    }

    // forwards
    if (
      forwards &&
      (lastCharPos == anchorOffset || distX > distX2 || key === "ArrowDown")
    ) {
      top = top2;
    }
    
    // backwards
    else {
      //console.log("back", lastCharPos, anchorOffset);
      if (lastCharPos > anchorOffset) {
        top = top2;
      }
    }

    // update
    lastCharPos = anchorOffset;
    lastTop = top;
  }

  // shift line indicator
  selectionLine.setAttribute("style", `top:${top}px; height:${height}px;`);
  cursor.setAttribute("style", `top:${bb.top}px; left:${bb.left}px;`);
}
```

```css
body{
  font-size: 2em;
  margin:0em;
  padding:11px;
}

*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrap{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;

}

.text-container {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}




.text-container:focus+
.selectionLine {
  border-left: 10px solid green;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  width:0;
  height:1em;
  top:0;
  right:0;

}

#cursor{
    position: absolute;
  width:0.2em;
  height:0.2em;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="info" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0;"></div>
<div class="wrap">
<div id="myText" class="text-container" contentEditable="true">Go on the last position in the first row and come it to first position in the second row. 
</div>
<div id="selectionLine" class="selectionLine"></div>
  </div>

<div id="cursor"></div>
```